# Creating Java stubs for a DLNA service / client? (or, What is a <scpd> root tag in an XML file?)

Tags: java, soap, code-generation, upnp, dlna

Looking at the specifications for DLNA, most of the metadata communication appears to be soap based.  However I can't find anything like a WSDL for any of the various services.  Instead there is some sort of service description language that looks like this:

```
<scpd>
  <serviceStateTable>
    <stateVariable>
      <Optional />
      <name>TransferIDs</name>
      <sendEventsAttribute>yes</sendEventsAttribute>
      <dataType>string</dataType>
      ...
    </stateVariable>
  </serviceStateTable>
  <actionList>
    <action>
      <name>Browse</name>
      <argumentList>
        <argument>
          <name>ObjectID</name>
          <direction>in</direction>
          <relatedStateVariable>A_ARG_TYPE_ObjectID</relatedStateVariable>
        </argument>
        ...
      </argumentList>
    </action>
    ...
  </actionList>
</scpd>
```

I can't find any documentation on this format or any tools to generate server or client stubs for it like I can with a WSDL.  At this point my options appear to be

1. Create an XSLT to try to transform the descriptor language *into* wsdl
2. Write java code generation tools that work from the existing descriptor language
3. Write stubs and code to serialize/deserialize the soap messages by hand

All three options seem pretty equally unappealing, though the first seems like the least work, not that that's saying much.  Any suggestions for getting a better handle on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately used a code generation tool to parse the XML manually and create client and server stubs.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, [ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) uses a similar approach to create a class per UPnP service (in your choice of C++, C#, Java, JavaScript or C) which handles all (de)serialization of soap messages.